# How can I DRY out this controller (angular 1.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component with a button. When that button is clicked, it calls one of two backend services. The service called depends on where the component is being used. So far I am passing in a flag to the component controller like this...

```
<run-report is-wizard="true" </run-report>
```

Using `isWizard: '<'` in the `component.js` file, and then I have the following code on the click event of a button in `run-report` ...

```
run() {
    if (this.running) {
        return;
    }

    this.running = true;

    //prepare the details for the report
    const reportDetails = this.prepareReportData({
        name: this.reportName,
        settings: this.mapSettings(this.selectedSettings),
    });

    if (this.isWizard) {

        return this.BackendService
            .postWizardReport(reportDetails)
            .then(response => {
                //do stuff
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.running = false;
            });

    } else {

        return this.BackendService
            .postMainReport(reportDetails)
            .then(response => {
                //do stuff
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.running = false;
            });
    }
}
```

I don't doing it this way as I'm repeating code. Can anyone suggest a better way? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the only difference is the name of the method then use array syntax instead of a dot:

```
var action = this.isWizard? 'postWizardReport' : 'postMainReport';
return this.BackendService
            [action](reportDetails)
            .then(response => {
                //do stuff
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.running = false;
            });
```